# foreign key doubt in MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql

can we define a primary key in a table as a foreign key in that table . I mean,

```
PRIMARY KEY(ssn),
 FOREIGN KEY (ssn) REFERENCES Cust(cust_ssn)
```

And If we have a table that has some parameters that refers to some other table parameters and to some other 3rd table too. Then Do we need to define those parameters as foreign key referencing to both the tables or Just only one.

Comment: Can you rephrase the second part of your question?

Comment: can we define the parameters of 1 table as foreign key refrencing to other 2 tables.

Comment: You can, although that's almost certainly not the best approach. I suggest opening another question here with some details of your schema to see if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Any field or combination of fields can be a foreign key.

Comment: Foreign keys are just costraints. A foreign key means that its value must be present in another table's column. +1 to VoteyDisciple